# rzc discover exited with code -2147450730

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, razor

I am writing a code but I'm waiting 3 or 4 months but I open my project and I show this error on rebuild.

> Error rzc discover exited with code -2147450730. ProjectName

I think that's error is rare I don't see this every time.

Exceptions (if any)

Further technical details
ASP.NET Core version 5.0 and others I install but project core 3
my dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK (varsa global.json dosyasını yansıtır):
 Version:   5.0.103
 Commit:    72dec52dbd

Çalışma Zamanı Ortamı:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.3
  Commit:  c636bbdc8a

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.103 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: ı see one thing for my error this line is that:<RazorTagHelper
but i am so confused what can i do for this :(

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/135